# GridBagConstraints insert a shifted column?

Tags: java, dictionary, constraints, textures, gridbaglayout

I'm using GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints to create a map (grid of texture)

[image]

but now I want to insert an edge between different texture: I want something like this

```
|-----|-----|-----|
|-----|-----|-----|
|----|-|----|-----|
|-----|-----|-----|
```

i have tried:

```
c.gridx = i*5;
c.gridy = j*5;
c.gridwidth = 5;
c.gridheight = 5;

if(right != null && right != currentTexture)
    c.gridwidth--;
if(left != null && left != currentTexture){
    c.gridx = i*5+1;
    c.gridwidth--;
}
```

but I'm getting this:

[image]

I'm using the same texture, but I want them to be cut off 1 position at the edge

@ Code-Guru Thanks for your interest. I found a different way to solve my problem: that is, cutting the image with the BufferedImage. I'll post the change to my code:

```
ImageIcon tile = //get texture ...
Image img = tile.getImage();
BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(tile.getIconWidth(),tile.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = buff.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);

int w = tile.getIconWidth(), h = tile.getIconHeight();
int x = 0, y = 0;
c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = i*10;
c.gridy = j*10;
c.gridwidth = 10;
c.gridheight = 10;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

if(right != null && right != texture){
    //c.gridwidth--;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    w -= (int)(res.ordinal()*2.5+2.5);
}
if(left != null && left != texture){
    //c.gridx = (i*10)+1;
    //c.gridwidth--;
    x = (int)(res.ordinal()*2.5+2.5);
    w -= (int)(res.ordinal()*2.5+2.5);
    if(c.anchor == GridBagConstraints.WEST)
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    else
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
}
BufferedImage buff2 = buff.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buff2));
globalMap.add(l, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you will need to start with a grid that has 5 columns per row. Then for each row, you will need to specify how many columns each cell will span.

For the first, second and fourth row in your example, the first cell spans two columns, the second cell spans two columns and the last cell only spans one column. For the third row, the first, third, and fourth cells span a single column and the second cell spans two columns.

p.s. You implement what I call "spanning" here by using the `gridwidth` member of your `GridBagConstraints` objects. You can set this with the constructor or directly.

Comment: in my code I tried exactly the same method, i have decided to use 5 columns and rows for each texture and when necessary to reduce to 4 for the left side and reduce to 4 and move the positioning for the right side ... but does not seem to work (the textures aren't cutted, only moved in strange ways)

Comment: @Giudark What do you mean "reduce to 4"? You can't reduce the number of columns. Rather, you specify the `gridwidth` to specify how many columns a cell will span in a given row.

Comment: @Giudark It might help to reduce your grid to two rows, for now. Post the code you use for these two rows and I can help you from there.

Comment: thanks but look at the change, I found a solution by cutting the image, I think the layout does not allow to add only a portion of the component